# Order order everywhere

Tags: mathematics, pattern, english

Something strange happened yesterday night. It is about a chain of images that I saw while sleeping, in dreams.

The following are the sequences I saw:

At 1 am, `F 4 6 T`

At 2 am, `E 4 1 N`

At 3 am, `I 5 0 I`

At 4 am, `R 4 9 U`

At 5 am , `H 3 5 F`

At 6 am,  I did not see any images or dreams.

At 6: 30 am my friend came and knocked the door. I woke up. The end!

I strongly believe that these images/sequences were following some pattern.

I am wondering whether I would have seen anything if I was asleep during 7 am? If yes, what would have been it?!

Help me answer these mysteries please.

Comment: Is the clock by your bed analog or digital?

Comment: I just have my mobile with me. No clocks at all!

Comment: If you don't have clocks how do you know what time you saw the images?

Comment: @corsiKa I propose that to be the true puzzle

Comment: @Bazul But it only makes sense if you know the dreams occurred on a particular hour and not before or after - so there must be a source of time. It's also very peculiar to say "I have my mobile, but no clocks" - there literally isn't a clock in any bedroom in my house - we all use our mobiles for knowing the time during the night.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

At 7am you would have seen:

> **H66S**
>
>  Take the hour to be N
>  the first column letter is the Nth letter in the **word** Nth
>  e.g.: The second (first column) letter, **E**, is the second letter in the word 'second'
>  The last column letter is the Nth from the end of the same word, ("Nth last")
>  e.g.: The second (last column) letter, **N**, is the second last letter in the word 'second'
>
>  If you assign a numerical value to each letter in sequence (A = 1, B = 2) you can sum the remaining letters of each word to product the number in the middle.
>
>  **S**e**CO**n**D** = S+C+O+D = 19+3+15+4 = **41**
>  Combine these to get **E41N**
>
>  Following this pattern for 7am:
>  The seventh letter of 'seventh' is **H**
>  The seventh-last letter of 'seventh' is **S**
>  Summing the remaining letters, s**EVENT**h:
>  5+22+5+14+20 = **66**
>
>  Combine them to get **H66S**

Nothing happens on the sixth hour because:

> The word sixth has no sixth letter, so it can't be used, giving you a single hour of dreamless bliss.

Answer (score 18):

Well, a partial answer goes like this:

> The first letters of the sequence represent the 'letters at respective position of the hour spelt'. That is **F**irst, s**E**cond, th**I**rd, and so on.. and the last letters are the letters in the reverse sequence. That is **T** is the first letter in reverse of FIRST, **N** is the 2nd letter in reverse of SECOND, and so on.

Hence, a fraction of full answer is

> **H** _ _ **S** ( for sevent**H** hour, that is 7 AM)